# multiple xampp with same vhost documentroot

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost, development-environment, document-root

I am developing a website app on my local environment using XAMPP.

At the moment my client server only serves PHP version 5, and after a few months they are going to upgrade the same web server to PHP version 7,,,

What I am thinking of doing is, develop using XAMPP of PHP7, and copy the exact source code to XAMPP of PHP5 (so I will have 2 XAMPP installed in my pc).This way i can test if the exact code does not break if it is in PHP5 environment.

But having to develop in PHP7 env, and the work of copying and pasting each time is more work than I have expected, not to mention the time taken to do that.

Is there anyway of setting the apache vhost of both XAMPP to point at the same documentroot? This way there is not need of copy paste anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible goto C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra

and edit httpd-vhosts.conf

and uncomment the line and add you root directory location like below example.and more like.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/test1"
    ServerName test1.com
    ErrorLog "logs/test1-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/test2"
    ServerName test2.com
    ErrorLog "logs/test2-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```